# How to find bluetooth devices not set to visible in python?

Tags: python, bluetooth, hidden, device

Im trying to make a algorithm in python to detect if my phone is in the area. Im using this to find my device:

bluetooth.discover_devices()

But it only detects my phone if I set my Bluetooth on my phone to "visible".

Is there a function or command to detect my phone when it's set to hidden?

Im fairly new to python so any form of help is very welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to connect to your phone.  If it's nearby, the connection will succeed.  Devices can be connectable when they are not discoverable.  You would have to already know the device address of your phone (via discovery when your phone was visible) in order to initiate the connection.

Comment: This sounds like a good solution. But how can I connect it that way?

Comment: Try to open an L2CAP socket to the device, see `sock.connect((bt_addr, port))` in the pybluez example: http://code.google.com/p/pybluez/source/browse/trunk/examples/advanced/l2-unreliable-client.py

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if a solution is still needed (I think this is right, just haven't been succesful with it).  A book entitled "Violent Python" gives a solution for this in chapter 5, but I haven't been successful in implementing it.  Supposedly you just need to increment the MAC address of the devices wifi adapter by one to calculate the Bluetooth MAC.

```
def retBtAddr(addr):
    btAddr=str(hex(int(addr.replace(':', ''), 16) + 1))[2:]
    btAddr=btAddr[0:2]+":"+btAddr[2:4]+":"+btAddr[4:6]+":"+\
    btAddr[6:8]+":"+btAddr[8:10]+":"+btAddr[10:12]
    return btAddr
```

and then something like the following (where OUI is the first 24 bytes of BT MAC)

```
def checkBluetooth(btAddr):
    btName = lookup_name(btAddr)
    if btName:
        print '[+] Detected Bluetooth Device: ' + btName
    else:
        print '[-] Failed to Detect Bluetooth Device.'

def wifiPrint(pkt):
    iPhone_OUI = 'd0:23:db'
    if pkt.haslayer(Dot11):
        wifiMAC = pkt.getlayer(Dot11).addr2
        if wifiMAC != None and iPhone_OUI == wifiMAC[:8]:
            print '[*] Detected iPhone MAC: ' + wifiMAC
            btAddr = retBtAddr(wifiMAC)
            print '[+] Testing Bluetooth MAC: ' + btAddr
            checkBluetooth(btAddr)
```